# how to go back and check for another input

Tags: python, if-statement, raw-input

is there a way to go back to this line of code to check for input again?:

```
say=raw_input("say: ")
```

after i do a if statement to check what the user inputed:

```
if say == "hello":
    do something
```

It does the if statement but then It ends the program and i have to run it again.I really don't want to have to start the file back up again. How do i make it where it goes back to that line of code to check for another input i enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a while loop:

```
while True:
    say = raw_input('say: ')
    if say == 'hello':
        print "hi!"
        break
    elif say == 'bye':
        print "bye!"
        break
```

`while True` is an infinite loop. Every time the loop loops, it will ask the user what they want to say. If the reply is "hello", then the loop will `break`. Same for if it was "bye".

If neither "hello" nor "bye" was given, then the loop will continue until it has been inputted.

Or, you can use this approach:

```
say = ''
while say not in ['hello', 'bye']:
    say = raw_input('say: ')

if say == 'hello':
    print "hi"
elif say == 'bye':
    print 'goodbye!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop, such as `while`:

```
while True:
    say = raw_input("say: ")
    if say == 'bye': break
    # do something
```

I suggest reading a [Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```
while True: # infinite loop
    say=raw_input("say: ")
    if say == "hello":
        # do something
    elif say == "quit":
        break # breaks out of loop
```